# List subscribers limit at 1000

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch a subscription list according to the [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) documentation. I want to get all my subscribers so I am using `mySubscribers=True` in the parameter list in a loop after my first request.

```
while "nextPageToken" in my_dict:
    next_page_token = my_dict["nextPageToken"]

    my_dict = subscriptions_list_by_channel_id(client,
        part='snippet,contentDetails',
        mySubscribers=True,
        maxResults=50,
        pageToken=next_page_token
        )

    for item in my_dict["items"]:
        file.write("{}\n".format(item["snippet"]["channelId"]))
```

The problem is at page 20 my loop breaks, i.e. I don't recieve a `nextPageToken` key in the response capping my data to 1000 total subscribers fetched. But I have more than 1000 subs. The documentation states that `myRecentSubscribers` has a limit at 1000 but that `mySubscribers` does not.

Can not really find much help with this anywhere. Any light on my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to list channels instead of listing subscriptions, passing the same argument `mySubscribers`. The documentations says it's deprecated and gives them back in a weird order with duplicates but it does not have a limit.

Comment: it does have 5050 limit unfortunately.

Comment: @smozgur At the time of writing it did not. I fetched over 20k subscribers but got a few duplicates at each request. Hopefully they have something better now.